# Multiple Schema.org ItemLists

Tags: schema.org

I have a page that lists multiple items, and each item has its own set of sub-items that are linked from there to their own separate pages. It looks something like this:

```
Title: Songs written by Person
Short Summary
Subheading: Pop Songs
               - List of pop songs, with links to each 
Subheading: Rock Songs
               - List of rock songs, with links to each 
Etc.
```

I've been just learning about Schema.org and can't wrap my mind around it. I understand I should probably use `CollectionPage` here, and I was thinking of marking each subheading as an `ItemList`.

The problem is that Google's Structured Data Testing Tool errors with ***Multiple ItemList markups on a page are not allowed*** when multiple `ItemList` are presented, and each `itemListElement` needs to have a set `position` property -- which in my case they really don't have.

What would then be a proper way to markup a page list this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s perfectly fine to have multiple `ItemList` items on a page, and it’s perfectly fine not to provide `position`.

With "not allowed", you are probably referring to Google’s guidelines for their [Carousels search result feature](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings). Google can’t decide what is/isn’t correct use of Schema.org, only Schema.org can do that. **There is only one case where you should follow Google’s guidelines:** If you want to get that specific Google search result feature for your page.

If you don’t want to get the feature, or if you can’t get the feature (it’s not possible for every page), you can ignore these guidelines.

From the perspective of Schema.org, your idea is correct:

- Use `CollectionPage`.
- Use an `ItemList` for each subsection’s list.

  (You could use one parent `ItemList` that has each subsection `ItemList` as entry, but I don’t think it’s useful to do this as long as each subsection `ItemList` is meaningful on its own.)
- The `itemListElement` property can have the entry (e.g., each `MusicRecording`) as direct value.

  (You only need to use `ListItem` if the order of the entries is relevant, in which case you should provide the `position` property.)

Answer (score 3):

> What would then be a proper way to markup a page list this?

It would be helpful if you provided your current markup to answer this. However, as [unor pointed out](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/122515/92667) it's acceptable to have multiple `ItemList` on a page despite the error Google's testing tool threw. To validate this claim run your markup through Yandex's structured data testing tool with multiple `ItemList` on a page and observe there is, in fact, no error thrown when multiple lists are present.

Regarding `position` param, it's relevant when the [`itemListOrder`](https://schema.org/itemListOrder) prop is *not* set to `Unordered`.

A snippet of your ideal mark-up might look something like:

```html
<h2>Bob Songs</h2>
<ul itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/ItemList">
  <meta itemprop="itemListOrder" content="Unordered">
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Bob Songs">
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/MusicComposition">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Natural Mystic">
    <a href="#" itemprop="url">07. Natural Mystic</a>
  </li>
  <li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/MusicComposition">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Sun Is Shining">
    <a href="#" itemprop="url">02. Sun is Shining</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then repeat that list for the next artist for as many artists as you need. And if you want more detailed structure Schema.org has [a good music example](https://schema.org/ItemList#ItemList-gen-217) to learn from.